# Netbeans ec2 tomcat server server location not valid

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, amazon-ec2

I want to set a webService on tomcat server on amazon ec2.

In Netbeans , in new Server wizard:
[image: Specify Server Location problem]

What is the right Server location

Comment: it is the tomcat path (catalina home). For example,  `/usr/share/tomcat6`

Comment: I tried http://***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/usr/share/tomcat8

but it didn't work.

I want to make a remote server not local

Comment: why you need http link? that's local path.

Comment: I want to set up connection to remote tomcat server that is on amazon ec2

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Integrate it into NetBeans and threw it the tomcat server was initialized